# How to remove only the latest sticky post from the loop

Tags: wp-query, loop, sticky-post

I know how to remove all of the sticky posts from a loop using the following argument

```
'post__not_in'  => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
```

But I am stuck in a problem. I want the loop to load all of the sticky posts except the latest one. That means only the latest sticky post won't render in the loop but the other old sticky posts will load as usual.

I want to do that coz I will make another query to render the latest sticky post on top of the main loop in a separate 'div'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

So if you're getting the sticky-post you want removed anyways

> I want to do that coz I will make another query to render the latest
>   sticky post on top of the main loop in a separate 'div'

Just make a variable, `$excludeSticky`, with it's ID, and add an `'post__not_in' => array($excludeSticky),` argument in your query.